# Redirect with .htaccess and remove query string on specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all requests to this link

`https://www.example.com/firstAccess?utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Benvenuto+su+Magazzino+Perfetto&utm_campaign=Benvenuto+Analytics`

at this link:

```
https://www.example.com/firstAccess
```

So, I need to remove everything after the word `firstAccess`.

Answer (score 0):

The additional part of the URL you wish to remove is the query string. You need to use mod_rewrite to check the query string (and remove it without leaving a  trailing `?`).

Try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Benvenuto+su+Magazzino+Perfetto&utm_campaign=Benvenuto+Analytics$
RewriteRule ^(firstAccess)$ /$1? [R,L]
```

This matches the exact URL as stated in your question.

The `$1` backreference simply serves to avoid repetition.

The trailing `?` on the *substitution* ensures the query string is removed from the redirected URL. If using Apache 2.4+ then you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support but this rule don't change nothing. Please check the link https://www.magazzinoperfetto.cloud/firstAccess?utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Benvenuto+su+Magazzino+Perfetto&utm_campaign=Benvenuto+Analytics

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? If so, add these to your question.

Comment: The .htaccess contains only your directives. Now I receive the 404 not found error... :(

Comment: But your "complete .htaccess file" that you've posted above contains a lot more than just these directives? And in your "complete .htaccess file" you have placed these directives in the wrong palce - so they may not get processed. As I mentioned above, these need to go "near the top" - crucially they must go above your "front controller".

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the .htaccess (see my first post) but the problem is the same :(

Comment: @GiovanniBroegg Did this eventually resolve your issue? I see from your "answer" that you used the exact code I posted in my answer and moved this to the top of your file (as stated in my answer). In your initial post, you had the rules in the wrong place (after the front-controller) - so they wouldn't have done anything initially.

Answer (score 0):

The complete `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Benvenuto+su+Magazzino+Perfetto&utm_campaign=Benvenuto+Analytics$
RewriteRule ^(firstAccess)$ /$1? [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion